# angularjs - resolve- gives error Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use resolve in AngularJS ngRoute.
But I get this error

On browser console I get the below error,

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: formTypeProvider <- formType <- addController

```
var myApp  = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/add', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/add.html',
        controller : "addController",
        resolve : {
            formType : function() {
                return 'CREATE';
            }
        }
    }).when('/view/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/view.html',
        controller : 'addController',
        resolve : {
            formType : function() {
                return 'VIEW';
            }
        }
    });
})



// Add
myApp.controller('addController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'formType', function($scope, $http, $location, formType) {

    console.log("formType : " +formType);
    //  
}
```

**Update:-**

Plunker : http://embed.plnkr.co/cLHnFGwt5it7T2itipG9/preview

Comment: do you also have `ng-controller` assigning same controller in html? Code shown should work fine

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks I added a Plunker, the browser console log still has that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the `ng-controller` in the HTML again. Remove `ng-controller` from HTML, then the problem will be solved.

See this pluker : http://embed.plnkr.co/0DI6Ogq640qn0Pp6YO8z/preview

Comment: Thanks. Should I never use ng-app & ng-conroller in index.html ?

Comment: Since you already defined the controller with the routes,  you should not add it again in the html.